# create multiple rows if a column has more than one value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like below :-

```
import pandas as pd 
  
# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'cust':['fnwp', 'utp'], 'events':[['abhi','ashu'],'abhi']} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
  
# Print the output. 
df
```

[image]

My expected outcome is :-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas.explode() function:

```
>>> df.explode('events').reset_index(drop=True)

   cust events
0  fnwp   abhi
1  fnwp   ashu
2   utp   abhi
```

Comment: The solution works on the df i have provided but its not working on my df which I am having. Do you have any clue why?

Comment: What is the result-error when you try it to your df?

Comment: nevermind I got it working actually i did some string operation and that's why it was not working! Thanks a lot!